# List not being appended during Try Except

Tags: python-2.7, arcmap

This is just a small snippet of what I have. Ultimately, I am checking an Esri Geodatabase for 2 types of RBJ Tables. If the tables are not there, I would like to append the name of the geodatabase to a new list.

I create a new empty list called missing_rbj. I need the code to check if there is a RBJ table, perform the required appending to CSV and if this errors out (because there is no RBJ table) then append the the aoi_name to the list. When I print the list at the end, it returns empty even though multiple items are flagged as No RBJ Exists. For some more background, this try except is inside of a for loop where x is the path to a geodatabase. I define aoi_name as the gdb name split from the original path.

```
    missing_rbj = []
    aoi_name = x.split("\\")[-1]
    aoi_name = aoi_name.replace(".gdb", "")

    try:
        ses_table = r'{0}\GDB_REVSESSIONTABLE'.format(x)

        ses_ids = {}
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ses_table, ['SESSIONID', 'USERNAME']) as ses_cursor:
            for row in ses_cursor:
                ses_ids[row[0]] = row[1]

        # REVCHECKRUNTABLE
        rev_table = os.path.join(x, "REVCHECKRUNTABLE")

        if arcpy.Exists(rev_table):
            rev_data = []
            rev_table_headers = ['SESSIONID', 'RECORDID', 'BATCHJOBDATETIME', 'BATCHJOBGROUPNAME', 'CHECKNAME',
                                 'CHECKTITLE', 'CHECKRUNCONTEXT', 'RESOURCENAME', 'TOTALVALIDATED', 'TOTALRESULTS']

            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(rev_table, rev_table_headers) as rev_cursor:
                for row in rev_cursor:
                    csv_write = []
                    analyst = ses_ids[row[0]]
                    for x in row:
                        csv_write.append(x)
                    csv_write.append(aoi_name)
                    csv_write.append(analyst[:2].upper())
                    csv_write.append(datetime.datetime.now())
                    rev_data.append(csv_write)

            with open(rbj_revcheck_csv, 'ab') as f:
                wr = csv.writer(f)
                for h in rev_data:
                    wr.writerow(h)

        # REVTABLEMAIN
        rev_main = r'{0}\REVTABLEMAIN'.format(x)

        if arcpy.Exists(rev_main):
            flds = [t.name for t in arcpy.ListFields(rev_main)]
            rev_data = []
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(rev_main, flds) as main_cursor:
                for row in main_cursor:
                    csv_write = []
                    for i in row:
                        csv_write.append(i)
                    csv_write.append(aoi_name)
                    csv_write.append(analyst[:2].upper())
                    csv_write.append(datetime.datetime.now())
                    rev_data.append(csv_write)

            with open(rbj_revmain_csv, 'ab') as f:
                wr = csv.writer(f)
                for h in rev_data:
                    wr.writerow(h)
        print "RBJ Good!\n"

    except:
        missing_rbj.append(aoi_name)
        print "No RBJ Exists in GDB.\n"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I have a feeling it is something I have overlooked multiple times. This has been quite a long project!

Answer (score 0):

Well like I said it was definitely something I was overlooking. I forgot because the empty list is in a for loop, it wouldn't be there anymore after the for loop was finished. I moved missing_rbj outside of the loop and it worked!